# rails Mechanize search without javascript and single data find

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-scraping

I started using rails Mechanize for scraping websites. The one problem is that i need to get simple data and i cant find any example how to get it on this real data:

```
<table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=1 border=0 width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td width="20%" align=center>
      <FONT FACE="arial,verdana,helvetica" SIZE="2">Car kg
      <br><b>2340</b>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I need to get this `2340` number. There are no Id's nor classes, so how should i get that info?

And the other problem is on another website. It is right-click protected website. So with javascript enabled i can't fetch the source. On chrome if i disable javascript, i can see the source. But with mechanize i dont know how to fetch the data. It says that there is no content. Because with javascript enabled there really can't get any content. How to disable javascript? With curl is the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're using chrome, you can use developer tools to help with. I'm sure something similar exists for Firefox as well.

Open the dev tools and click the 'elements' tab. You will see a page source.

Click the button in the top left of dev tools to start the "inspector", then click your target text on the actual web page. This should highlight the DOM node in the dev tools view.

Then right click the selected DOM node in the dev tools. Hover over 'copy' to find the `copy selector` option. Clicking this will add a CSS selector to your clipboard - paste anywhere to view it.

This approach is especially useful in a situation like this - when writing a CSS selector by hand would be difficult.

As for your second question - using Mechanize with Javascript-reliant sites, I'm not sure if there's as simple a solution. You might have to use Capybara, Selenium, or PhantomJS.